# How to make a bash script wait after running SSH command?

Tags: ssh, bash

I am currently writing a bash script to help me update some servers, so I need to connect there, run `yum update -y` and then sometimes type in additional commands. I do currently have this set up:

```
for servers in $devservers
    do
        ssh $servers 'yum update -y'
    done
```

But the problem is that when I run this, it won't allow me to write some additional commands in case I need to - like when I need to restart certain services. Is there a way to make the script wait for me until I log out of the server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need shell access after the `yum` ends, you need to run a `bash` or your preferred shell. Also using `-t` will help you to work properly (allocate remote TTY).

```
for servers in $devservers
    do
        ssh -t $servers 'yum update -y;bash'
    done
```

Comment: works exactly how I wanted. thank you very much sir !

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by requesting a tty:

```
for servers in $devservers
     do
           ssh -tt $servers 'stty raw -echo; sudo yum update -y'
     done
```

Comment: you can use `< <(cat)` at the end of the command line, but, that would put the password in clear.

Comment: not working, only shows the same output but moved a few whitespaces here and there. I have also tried running /bin/bash command or ssh-ing to localhost, but since we use different ports then the standart ones, I will either have to search for better solution or somehow make the script use the different port numbers

Comment: And does it works as command line?

Comment: could you explain your question please ?